# Get Excel.Application object from Process or hwnd in .NET

Tags: c#, excel

In C# I am trying to get an instance of an Excel.Application object from a Process object. This seems like it should be really simple yet I cannot figure it out and cannot find an example. To repeat, I have a System.Diagnostics.Process object that I know refers to a running Excel instance. I now need to recover a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object that refers to the process so that I can go about manipulating the Excel application from C#.

In case it makes it any simpler, I also have the HWND id and window text associated with the active Excel window.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Excel instance or Excel instance CLSID using the Process ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770173/how-to-get-excel-instance-or-excel-instance-clsid-using-the-process-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on another SO post:

[How to get Excel instance or Excel instance CLSID using the Process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770173/how-to-get-excel-instance-or-excel-instance-clsid-using-the-process-id)

Comment: I am not clear on how this is an answer, as the other thread gives you a `IntPtr HWind` of the Excel instance, but it still doesn't give you `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` object... Am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, the reason why I was confused was because the answer is actually related to an external link that does not work anymore. In fact, someone else posted the code @ http://pastebin.com/F7gkrAST

Answer (score 2):

[How to use Visual C# to automate a running instance of an Office program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126)

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
:    

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    //Excel Application Object
    Excel.Application oExcelApp;

    this.Activate();

    //Get reference to Excel.Application from the ROT.
    oExcelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    //Display the name of the object.
    MessageBox.Show(oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name);

    //Release the reference.
    oExcelApp = null;
}
```

Not sure if you strictly need to retrieve application object from the Process class? Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have already considered this option. Unfortunately this common approach does not work for me because I need to be able to get the last active Excel window regardless of how many instances of Excel there are running. GetActiveObject will always deliver a reference to the same Excel instance even if there are multiple instances running.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a class that can iterate through all running Excel instances, and also lookup Application instances by Hwnd, ProcessID, or a Process object.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080611/Get-a-Collection-of-All-Running-Excel-Instances

The answer is basically a lot of ugly extern calls to the Win32 API, which are best left hidden behind a clean public interface.

This has not been tested on all version of Excel or Windows.