# Get last activated Excel instance from Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight application that is running in the browser with the elevated trust functionality that is available to in-browser applications in Silverlight 5. I would like to use the application to pass data to an already running instance of Excel (i.e. an instance of Excel not started by the Silverlight application itself). Of key importance is that I want to get the last activated (selected) instance of Excel when there are multiple instances.

I have done something like this in a regular .NET desktop application; a discussion of the issues is summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770173/how-to-get-excel-instance-or-excel-instance-clsid-using-the-process-id). Unfortunately this example uses .NET classes that are not in Silverlight, such as `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Is there another way to go about this in Silverlight?

Note that I already know how to get the first running instance of Excel:

> using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;
>
> ...
>
> dynamic excel = AutomationFactory.GetObject("Excel.Application");