# How to get instance using the Process object

Tags: c#, excel

What I am trying to do is to write a method to loop through all opened excel instances and figure out if a specific excel file is already opened. If it is, then pass out the excel instance with the open file for further work.

My struggle is how to convert a process object to an Excel.Application so that I can loop through the workbooks in the instance.

I did read through the answers in a similar post [How to get Excel instance or Excel instance CLSID using the Process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770173/how-to-get-excel-instance-or-excel-instance-clsid-using-the-process-id). However, the article [Getting the Application Object in a Shimmed Automation Add-in](http://blogs.officezealot.com/whitechapel/archive/2005/04/10/4514.aspx) by Andrew Whitechapel referred by Mike in his answer is not accessible any more.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace test
{
    public class try
    {
        private bool IsExcelOpened(string wbookname, out Excel.Application exApp)
        {
            bool isOpened = false;
            Excel.Application exl=new Excel.Application();

            Process[] allopenexcel = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
            foreach (Process excl in allopenexcel)
            {

                exl=MagicConversionFromProcessToExcel(excl)   // struggle here, how to do this

                foreach (Excel.Workbook wb in exl.Workbooks)
                {
                    if (wb.Name == wbookname)
                    {
                        isOpened = true;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 if (isOpened) break;
             }

            exApp = exl;
            return isOpened;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130518152056/http://blogs.officezealot.com/whitechapel/archive/2005/04/10/4514.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've created a class that can iterate through all currently running Excel instances, and also lookup Application objects by ProcessID, Hwnd, or a Process object.  The code is below, but check the link for some further description.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080611/Get-a-Collection-of-All-Running-Excel-Instances

This has not been tested on all versions of Excel or Windows.

---

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//Don't add the entire interop namespace, it will introduce some naming conflicts.
using xlApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using xlWin = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window;


namespace ExcelExtensions {

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of currently running Excel instances.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExcelAppCollection : IEnumerable<xlApp>  {

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the 
        /// <see cref="ExcelAppCollection"/> class.</summary>
        /// <param name="sessionID">Windows sessionID to filter instances by.
        /// If not assigned, uses current session.</param>
        public ExcelAppCollection (Int32? sessionID = null) {
            if (sessionID.HasValue && sessionID.Value < -1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sessionID");

            this.SessionID = sessionID
                ?? Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>Gets the Windows sessionID used to filter instances.
        /// If -1, uses instances from all sessions.</summary>
        /// <value>The sessionID.</value>
        public Int32 SessionID { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Accessors

        /// <summary>Gets the Application associated with a given process.</summary>
        /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with process.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">process</exception>
        public xlApp FromProcess(Process process) {
            if (process == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("process");
            return InnerFromProcess(process);
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the Application associated with a given processID.</summary>
        /// <param name="processID">The process identifier.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with processID.</returns>
        public xlApp FromProcessID(Int32 processID) {
            try {
                return FromProcess(Process.GetProcessById(processID));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Get the Application associated with a given window handle.</summary>
        /// <param name="mainHandle">The window handle.</param>
        /// <returns>Application associated with window handle.</returns>
        public xlApp FromMainWindowHandle(Int32 mainHandle) {
            return InnerFromHandle(ChildHandleFromMainHandle(mainHandle));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the main instance. </summary>
        /// <remarks>This is the oldest running instance.
        /// It will be used if an Excel file is double-clicked in Explorer, etc.</remarks>
        public xlApp PrimaryInstance {
            get {
                try {
                    return Marshal.GetActiveObject(MarshalName) as xlApp;
                }
                catch (COMException) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the top most instance.</summary>
        /// <value>The top most instance.</value>
        public xlApp TopMostInstance {
            get {
                var topMost = GetProcesses() //All Excel processes
                    .Select(p => p.MainWindowHandle) //All Excel main window handles
                    .Select(h => new { h = h, z = GetWindowZ(h) }) //Get (handle, z) pair per instance
                    .Where(x => x.z > 0) //Filter hidden instances
                    .OrderBy(x => x.z) //Sort by z value
                    .First(); //Lowest z value

                return FromMainWindowHandle(topMost.h.ToInt32());
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.</summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1" /> 
        /// that can be used to iterate through the collection.
        /// </returns>
        public IEnumerator<xlApp> GetEnumerator() {
            foreach (var p in GetProcesses())
                yield return FromProcess(p);
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

        /// <summary>Gets all Excel processes in the current session.</summary>
        /// <returns>Collection of all Excel processing in the current session.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<Process> GetProcesses() {

            IEnumerable<Process> result = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);

            if (this.SessionID >= 0)
                result = result.Where(p => p.SessionId == SessionID);

            return result;
        }

        #endregion

//------------Implementation

        #region Methods

        private static xlApp InnerFromProcess(Process p) {
            return InnerFromHandle(ChildHandleFromMainHandle(p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()));
        }

        private static Int32 ChildHandleFromMainHandle(Int32 mainHandle) {
            Int32 handle = 0;
            EnumChildWindows(mainHandle, EnumChildFunc, ref handle);
            return handle;
        }

        private static xlApp InnerFromHandle(Int32 handle) {
            xlWin win = null;
            Int32 hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(handle, DW_OBJECTID, rrid.ToByteArray(), ref win);
            return win.Application;
        }

        private static Int32 GetWindowZ(IntPtr handle) {
            var z = 0;
            for (IntPtr h = handle; h != IntPtr.Zero; h = GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDPREV))
                z++;
            return z;
        }

        private static Boolean EnumChildFunc(Int32 hwndChild, ref Int32 lParam) { 
            var buf = new StringBuilder(128); 
            GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128); 
            if (buf.ToString() == ComClassName) { 
                lParam = hwndChild; 
                return false; 
            } 
            return true; 
        }

        #endregion

        #region Extern Methods

        [DllImport("Oleacc.dll")] 
        private static extern Int32 AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
            Int32 hwnd, UInt32 dwObjectID, Byte[] riid, ref xlWin ptr); 

        [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
        private static extern Boolean EnumChildWindows(
            Int32 hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, ref Int32 lParam); 

        [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
        private static extern Int32 GetClassName(
            Int32 hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, Int32 nMaxCount); 

        [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 uCmd);

        #endregion

        #region Constants & delegates

        private const String MarshalName = "Excel.Application";

        private const String ProcessName = "EXCEL";

        private const String ComClassName = "EXCEL7";

        private const UInt32 DW_OBJECTID = 0xFFFFFFF0;

        private const UInt32 GW_HWNDPREV = 3;
        //3 = GW_HWNDPREV
        //The retrieved handle identifies the window above the specified window in the Z order.
        //If the specified window is a topmost window, the handle identifies a topmost window.
        //If the specified window is a top-level window, the handle identifies a top-level window.
        //If the specified window is a child window, the handle identifies a sibling window.

        private static Guid rrid = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        private delegate Boolean EnumChildCallback(Int32 hwnd, ref Int32 lParam);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can safely say that if Excel is not open then the file you're checking for is not open, right?

So, your process here should be to check if Excel is running. If not, return `false`.

If Excel is running, all need to do is create a new instance of Excel for that process and loop through the workbooks. There's no need to try to turn the process into an instance.

```
Process[] allopenexcel = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
if(allopenexcel.count==0)
{
    isOpened = false;
    break;
}
else
{
    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process excl in allopenexcel)
    {
        Excel.Application exl = new Excel.Application();
        for (int i = 1; i <= exl.Workbooks.Count; i++)
        {
            if (exl.Workbooks(i).FullName == wbookname)
            {
                isOpened = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        exl.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logical branch isn't necessary (even if it were, the `break` statement isn't necessary) - if `allopenexcel` contains no elements, the `foreach` loop will iterate zero times. More to the question, at no point do you actually do anything with the `Process` instances - you're creating a new instance of `Excel.Application` independent of the `Process` instance.

Comment: Thanks Seth for the suggestion. However, I agree with Preston's comment. Your code doesn't really work on the Process array.